# Ejecutar script con InnerHtml sin usar eval();

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy insertando un `<script>` al final del body con un innerHtml, pero no se ejecuta el script.No puedo usar la función eval(), porque no pasará el fortify.

¿ Cómo hago para que ejecute el script ?. Este es mi principal problema...
Intenté usar el onLoad con el insertAdjacentHTML pero tampoco consigo que funcione.

```
<html class="no-js" lang="es">
    <head> 
        <script src="js/spp.js"></script>
        <script src="elementos.js"></script>
        <script src="transform_multiproducto_asistente.js"></script>

        <script>
            function transform(){
                cargarProducto();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
     <body class="spp-loading" onload="transform();">
        <main class="spp-main">
            <article id="zona_despliegue">
            </article>
        </main>
        <div id="transform">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
<script src="elementos.js"></script>
```

Es un .js con funciones para generar etiquetas -> `function generarP() {return "<p>"; }`

```
<script src="transform_multiproducto_asistente.js"></script>
```

Es donde tengo las funciones de coger el JSON del servidor y generar el html y el script.
Se empieza a ejecutar con cargarProducto();

Finalmente cuando ejecuto, no pasa nada porque no se ha ejecutado el script, pero si inspecciono, está creado bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function procesar(JSON){

    var cadena=procesarComponenteMultiProductoAsistente(JSON.pasos);
    cadena+=abrirDivConId("js-spp-assistant")+cerrarDiv();
    document.getElementById(JSON.areaCarga).innerHTML+=cadena;
    cadena=generarScriptAsistente(JSON);
    /*

    document.getElementById(JSON.areaCarga).innerHTML+=cadena;
    var ele = document.getElementById(JSON.areaCarga);
    var codes=document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for(var i=0;i<codes.length;i++){
        eval(codes[i].text);
    }
    */

       var div = document.getElementById("transform");
       div.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', cadena);
}
```

Este es el fragmento de código que ejecuta la creación del script.
Lo he intentado con el innerhtml, con el insertAdj y poniéndolo al final del body y no consigo hacer que funcione...

Solamente con la opción comentada "eval" hace que funcione, pero no puedo usarla, porque no pasará fortify en un futuro.

**Edito**: El problema es que el contenido HTML es añadido dinámicamente y finalmente, se añade el script> al html, es decir, no es el que el contenido del html ya estuviese y sólo se genere el script.

Cómo se ve en el código HTML que dejé, solo tengo el main y el article en el html.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿`generarScriptAsistente` es una función de javascript que genera un script en el cliente? ¿Podrías hacer que el script se generara en el servidor y luego añadirlo al html mediante un `<script src="">`?

Comment: Hola Javi, sí, es un script que se genera en el cliente. no, no puedo hacer que se genere en el servidor, a mí del servidor me vendrán unos datos en un json, y yo en el cliente tengo que generar un script con los datos de Json. básicamente es una variable.

Comment: @JaviMollá El contenido del html es creado con la función cargarProducto(); y  más adelante, el contenido del script> es agregado después, es decir, yo no tengo contenido en el html.

Comment: Esa variable la querrás usar en alguna otra función. ¿Por qué no le pasas el objeto json a la función que necesite esa variable directamente?

Comment: La variable es un monstruo muy grande de arrays de arrays, links,imgs etc.... la forma más cómoda es dejar la variable en un script> y que la coga el elemento html que la necesite...

Comment: porque no haces una solicitud AJAX? la llamas y listo , esta en un servidor, es un json usa AJAX no tendras ni un problema, de igual forma al ser un json en el cliente lo pueden sobreescribir

Comment: Eso es lo que he hecho ... he obtenido la respuesta en un JSON.....

Comment: me vas a decir que lo que te viene en el json no es un texto de un código si no que es un objeto javascript que no quieres procesar con un algorítmo sino que quieres que automáticamente se cree un código que lo procese? es eso lo que quieres? no me queda claro tu dilema, creí entenderlo hasta que leí los comentarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes añadir un script de manera dinámica así.

```js
const valor=document.getElementById('texto').innerText;
let codigo='console.log("Hola ' +valor+'");' + 'console.log("'+holaMundo+'");';


let script=document.createElement('script');
script.text = codigo;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

```html
<script>
  var holaMundo='Hola Mundo';
</script>
<div id="texto">EDU</div>
```

Al usar appendChild nos aseguramos que se añade al final de todo, con lo que todas las variables y elementos que se hayan creado en el documento deberían estar disponibles sin problema, se ejecute cuando se ejecute el código.