# ¿Cómo usar una función PHP desde JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Siento preguntar lo que parece saber todo el mundo, pero de mil explicaciones leídas no he sabido aprovechar ninguna...y con 7 libros comprados: tampoco.

Desde `JavaScript` necesito llamar a una función de `PHP` pasando dos parámetros de tipo `string`. La función `PHP` retorna un `string` de respuesta que debe volver a `JavaScript`.

Fichero **index.html:**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample 9</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="funcionesJS.js"></script>
        <script src="funcionesPHP.php"></script>
        <script src="f_JSviaPHP.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
            var PotenciaJS = "0";
            var PotenciaPHP = "0";

            var Base = "4";
            var Exponente = "2";
            PotenciaJS = DamePotencia(Base, Exponente);
            alert("Potencia JS: " + Base + " ^ " + Exponente + " = " + PotenciaJS);

            Base = "3";
            Exponente = "3";
            PotenciaPHP = DamePotenciaViaPHP(Base, Exponente);
            alert("Potencia PHP: " + Base + " ^ " + Exponente + " = " + PotenciaPHP);
        </SCRIPT>
    </body>
</html>
```

Calculo `PotenciaJS` con la función `DamePotencia` del fichero `funcionesJS.js`.mSencillo y funciona:

```js
function DamePotencia(base, exponente) {
    return  parseFloat( eval(base) ** eval(exponente) );
}
```

Pero necesito imperiosamente que el proceso sea en el servidor con `PHPDamePotencia` que está en el fichero `funcionesPHP.php`:

```js
<?php
    function PHPDamePotencia($base, $exponente) {
        $respuesta = strval( pow(floatval($base), floatval($exponente)) );
        return $respuesta;
    }

    $base = $_POST["base"];
    $exponente = $_POST["exponente"];
    $strOUT = PHPDamePotencia($base, $exponente);
    echo ($strOUT);
?>
```

Entonces aparece `AJAX`. Tengo el fichero `f_JSviaPHP.js` con la función `PHPDamePotencia`:

```js
//crear un objeto XMLHttpRequest
function getxmlhttp() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    //Comprobar si se está utilizando Internet Explorer.
    try {
        //Si la versión de JavaScript es superior a la 5.
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        //En caso contrario, utilizar el tradicional objeto ActiveX.
        try {
            //Si se está utilizando Internet Explorer.
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
            //En caso contrario, no se está utilizando Internet Explorer.
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }

 //Si no se está usando Internet Explorer, crear una instancia JavaScript del objeto.
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    return xmlhttp;

}

function DamePotenciaViaPHP(base, exponente) {
    var xmlhttp = getxmlhttp();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            return document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML;
        } else {
            return "MAL";
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "funcionesPHP.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send("PHPDamePotencia?base=" + base + "&exponente=" + exponente);

}
```

Pero esto no va.

He puesto aquí un ejemplo de los mil intentos que llevo en unos cinco meses. Espero que sea reparable.

Comment: ¿7 libros y 5 meses y no has logrado hacerlo funcionar? Hace rato que tenías que haber pregunta aquí y ya lo habrías resuelto. Vamos por partes. ¿Qué ocurre con el código actual? ¿Imprime la palabra `MAL`? ¿Da algún error? Si da error ponlo en la pregunta. ¿No hace nada? ¿Se queda en blanco? ¿Se bloquea la PC? ¿Coge fuego el servidor? Mientras más claro seas más rápido podrá resolverse.

Comment: Pues... Ejecutando, aparece primero: Potencia JS: 4 ^ 2 = 16 ... y en Aceptar, aparece: Potencia PHP: 3 ^ 3 = undefined. Aceptas y se acabó.

Comment: Mas... La palabra MAL no aparece por ninguna parte. Error no manifiesta ninguno.

Comment: Hace un par de semanas conseguí que funcionara... y me dije: "A guardar!!!" Antes de hacerlo cambié convenientemente el nombre de un fichero y seguía funcionando. Hice dos copias de todos los ficheros (es decir lo tenía en tres sitios). Pues bien... Nada ha vuelto a funcionar.

Comment: Observo que el Editor Chrome, cuando editando yo, genero un error, simplemente se queda con la versión anterior... y no me entero. Así que aquel inocente cambio de nombre debió crear un error... y salvé el error. Pero me ha resultado irrecuperable.

Comment: Igual que tengo la función PHPDamePotencia, debería tener JSDamePotencia, sin embargo tengo simplemente DamePotencia. Pues bien, es un nombre que no se deja cambiar. ¡Vaya tela!... Gracias compañero.

Comment: Sospechaba que algún error en alguna parte evitaba el cambio de nombre de la función. Cuando con la Respuesta 2 todo funcionaba normal, he vuelto a intentarlo: 8-12 veces he tenido que hacerlo para que Chrome lo aceptara. Pregunto: Cuando actualizas... ¿Se actualiza todo o sólo lo que a Chrome le da la gana?... GRACIAS.

Comment: Te pido por favor que leas el [tour] y tambien [ask]. recuerda aceptar la respuesta que soluciono tu problema, y en lo posible limitar las preguntas a una por publicación.

Answer (score 3):

Primero que todo, se agradece que hayas mostrado todo el código que has intentado hasta el momento, se ve que has trabajado bastante en esto, pero como recomendación, cuando veas que estás atascado, ven rápido con el código que tengas en ese momento y los problemas que hayas presentado, no esperes cinco meses para hacerlo, esto evitará que tu código vaya creciendo y vaya acumulando más y más errores :)

Trataré de ir por puntos indicándote dónde hay errores en tu código a la misma vez que te iré dando consejos y buenas prácticas:

1 - Hoy en día no hace falta que detectes capacidades del navegador para saber si construyes un objeto [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) o un `ActiveXObject`. Si no necesitas soportar versiones de Internet Explorer menores que la versión 8 (y [no deberías](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-ie-support)), puedes usar sin ningún problema `XMLHttpRequest`. En los ejemplos que te mostraré asumiré que estás trabajando mínimo con Internet Explorer 10.

2 - No debes incluir un fichero `PHP` como si de un fichero `JavaScript` se tratase. El código `PHP` es para ejecutarlo en el servidor, por lo que no hace falta que hagas referencia a él. La siguiente línea:

```
<script src="funcionesPHP.php"></script>
```

La deberías eliminar.

3 - Si tus funciones hacen cálculos numéricos, lo mejor es que declares variables numéricas en vez de cadenas, esto te evitará tener que estar haciendo conversiones innecesarias una y otra vez.

4 - [Intenta no usar `eval`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192300/en-qu%C3%A9-momento-se-vuelve-necesario-usar-la-funci%C3%B3n-eval-de-javascript). En tu caso, lo estás usando solo para convertir las variables de tipo de cadena a numéricas, pero si sigues mi recomendación anterior o usas el operador `+`, [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt), o haces un cast a `Number` no necesitas hacer uso del mismo:

```js
var variable = "100";

console.log(typeof +variable);
console.log(typeof parseInt(variable));
console.log(typeof Number(variable));
```

5 - El `return` que haces dentro del `onreadystatechange` no tiene el efecto que esperas. Crees que es el retorno de la función `DamePotenciaViaPHP`, pero en realidad esta última no tiene ningún retorno, por lo que siempre te devolverá `undefined`. Observa el siguiente snippet:

```js
// Esta función no tiene un retorno por lo que siempre
// devolverá undefined
function prueba (numero) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    // Este retorno afecta a la función enviada
    // al setTimeout, no afecta a la función prueba
    return numero++;
  }, 100);

}

console.log( prueba(2) );
```

6 - Por otro lado, debes tener en cuenta, que cuando haces una llamada `AJAX`, la respuesta del servidor es asíncrona, por lo que no estará inmediatamente disponible. No debes intentar igualar la respuesta de la función a una variable de esa manera, porque como te comentaba anteriormente la función que estás usando devuelve `undefined`. Observa el siguiente snippet para que comprendas que el valor devuelto por `PHP` lo recibes después del momento en que estás intentando obtener su valor:

```js
function getTodos() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', true);
  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      console.log("Este console.log se ejecutará más tarde, en este momento es realmente cuando se obtiene el valor que estás intentando guardar en la variable PotenciaPHP");
    }
  };
  request.send();
}

getTodos();

console.log("este console.log se ejecutará primero, en este momento estás intentando asignar un valor a PotenciaPHP pero el mismo no está disponible");
```

Por lo tanto, este código no hará lo que estás buscando:

```
PotenciaPHP = DamePotenciaViaPHP(Base, Exponente);
alert("Potencia PHP: " + Base + " ^ " + Exponente + " = " + PotenciaPHP);
```

Ya que el valor que el servidor devolverá no estará disponible en el momento en que estás intentando acceder a él. Para hacer lo que buscas, debes usar o un `callback` o una [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) para ejecutar el código que necesita acceder a los datos una vez que estos sean devueltos.

7 - Otro problema que tienes es que estás intentando acceder en `PHP` a variables enviadas por `POST`:

```
$base = $_POST["base"];
$exponente = $_POST["exponente"];
```

Sin embargo en el código `JavaScript` haces una petición `GET`:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "funcionesPHP.php", true);
```

8 - No sé que estás intentando en la siguiente línea:

```
xmlhttp.send("PHPDamePotencia?base=" + base+"&exponente=" + exponente);
```

Pero solo debes enviar las variables `base` y `exponente` al servidor, la primera parte relativa a `PHPDamePotencia` sobraría, te debería quedar así:

```
xmlhttp.send("base=" + base+"&exponente=" + exponente);
```

9 - Y finalmente, estás escribiendo el resultado devuelto por el servidor en un supuesto elemento que no veo en tu código `HTML`

```
document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = this.responseText;
return document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML;
```

Si el elemento con `id` `myText` no existe, el anterior código te debería lanzar un error ya que `getElementById` devolvería `null`.

Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, aquí te dejo una variación de tu código que te debería funcionar. Fíjate como el tercer parámetro de la función `DamePotenciaViaPHP` es una función `callback`:

```
function DamePotenciaViaPHP(base, exponente, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "funcionesPHP.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.onload = function() {
        // Una vez recibida la respuesta del servidor
        callback(
            xmlhttp.status === 200
                ? +xmlhttp.responseText
                : 'MAL'
        );
    };
    xmlhttp.send("base=" + base + "&exponente=" + exponente);
}
```

Y para llamar a la función, lo haces de la siguiente manera:

```
DamePotenciaViaPHP(Base, Exponente, function (PotenciaPHP) {
    alert("Potencia PHP: " + Base + " ^ " + Exponente + " = " + PotenciaPHP);
});
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100220/discussion-on-answer-by-elchininet-como-usar-una-funcion-php-desde-javascript).