# Iterando objetos y metodos con javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase para realizar una ajedrez con JavaScript, y debemos colocar unas piezas en un tablero.

Como primer paso creo la clase, con sus atributos, método constructor y método colocar y retirar pieza.

Me surgen dos dudas:

1. Método colocar, resulta que el nombre de los objetos son similares (solo se diferencia el último dígito, y quiero llamar al método desde un bucle for, pero no me lo reconoce.

Aunque se puede hacer llamando a los objetos de uno en uno la idea es optimizar el código e iterando los diversos métodos.

2. El método retirar, me da error al no encontrar el elemento a borrar.

Gracias.

Pongo el código:

```js
class pieza {

    constructor(id, figura, valor, posicion, blanca) {
        this.id = id;
        this.figura = figura;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.posicion = posicion;
        this.blanca = true;
    }

    colocar() {
        document.getElementById(this.id).appendChild(document.createElement("span")).appendChild(document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(this.figura)));
    }

    retirar() {
        document.getElementById(this.id).removeChild(document.getElementById(this.posicion));
    }
}

pieza1 = new pieza("a7", "9820", "torre_negra_1", "a7", false);
pieza2 = new pieza("b7", "9822", "caballo_negro_1", "b7", false);
pieza3 = new pieza("c7", "9821", "alfil_negro_1", "c7", false);
pieza4 = new pieza("d7", "9819", "reina_negra_1", "d7", false);
pieza5 = new pieza("e7", "9818", "reina_negra_1", "d7", false);
pieza6 = new pieza("f7", "9821", "reina_negra_1", "f7", false);
pieza7 = new pieza("g7", "9822", "reina_negra_1", "g7", false);
pieza8 = new pieza("h7", "9820", "reina_negra_1", "h7", false);

var ejemplo = [];

for (let index = 1; index < 9; index++) {
    ejemplo[index] = "pieza" + index;
    console.log(ejemplo[index]);
}

//aqui no reconoce al método colocar
for (let index = 1; index < 9; index++) {
    ejemplo[index].colocar();

}
```

```css
#cabecera {
    align-content: center;
}
#tablero {
    width:980px;
    height:700px;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

.celda{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    float:left;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}
.celda span{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.blanca {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.negra {
    background-color: #666;
}

.roja {
    background-color: rgb(250, 24, 24);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ajedrez</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <script src="index2.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav id="cabecera"></nav>
    <main id="tablero">
        <div id="fila1">
            <div id="minBl" class="celda">05</div>
            <div id="segBl" class="celda">00</div>
            <div class="celda"></div>
            <div class="celda">a</div>
            <div class="celda">b</div>
            <div class="celda">c</div>
            <div class="celda">d</div>
            <div class="celda">e</div>
            <div class="celda">f</div>
            <div class="celda">g</div>
            <div class="celda">h</div>
            <div class="celda"></div>
            <div id="minNg" class="celda roja"><span>05</span></div>
            <div id="segNg" class="celda roja"><span>00</span></div>
        </div>
        <div id="fila2">
            <div id="negras1" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="negras2" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                8
            </div>
            <div id="a8" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="b8" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="c8" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="d8" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="e8" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="f8" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="g8" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="h8" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                8
            </div>
            <div id="blancas1" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="blancas2" class="celda negra">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fila3">
            <div id="negras3" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="negras4" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                7
            </div>
            <div id="a7" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="b7" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="c7" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="d7" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="e7" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="f7" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="g7" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="h7" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                7
            </div>
            <div id="blancas3" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="blancas4" class="celda negra">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fila4">
            <div id="negras5" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="negras6" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                6
            </div>
            <div id="a6" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="b6" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="c6" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="d6" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="e6" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="f6" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="g6" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="h6" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                6
            </div>
            <div id="blancas5" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="blancas6" class="celda negra">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fila5">
            <div id="negras7" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="negras8" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                5
            </div>
            <div id="a5" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="b5" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="c5" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="d5" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="e5" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="f5" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="g5" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="h5" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                5
            </div>
            <div id="blancas7" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="blancas8" class="celda negra">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fila6">
            <div id="negras9" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="negras10" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                4
            </div>
            <div id="a4" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="b4" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="c4" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="d4" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="e4" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="f4" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="g4" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="h4" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                4
            </div>
            <div id="blancas9" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="blancas10" class="celda negra">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fila7">
            <div id="negras11" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="negras12" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                3
            </div>
            <div id="a3" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="b3" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="c3" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="d3" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="e3" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="f3" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="g3" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="h3" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                3
            </div>
            <div id="blancas11" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="blancas12" class="celda negra">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fila8">
            <div id="negras13" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="negras14" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                2
            </div>
            <div id="a2" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="b2" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="c2" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="d2" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="e2" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="f2" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="g2" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="h2" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                2
            </div>
            <div id="blancas13" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="blancas14" class="celda negra">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fila9">
            <div id="negras15" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="negras16" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                1
            </div>
            <div id="a1" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="b1" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="c1" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="d1" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="e1" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="f1" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div id="g1" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="h1" class="celda blanca">

            </div>
            <div class="celda">
                1
            </div>
            <div id="blancas15" class="celda negra">

            </div>
            <div id="blancas16" class="celda negra">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fila10">
            <div class="celda"></div>
            <div class="celda"></div>
            <div class="celda"></div>
            <div class="celda">a</div>
            <div class="celda">b</div>
            <div class="celda">c</div>
            <div class="celda">d</div>
            <div class="celda">e</div>
            <div class="celda">f</div>
            <div class="celda">g</div>
            <div class="celda">h</div>
            <div class="celda"></div>
            <div class="celda"></div>
            <div class="celda"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usa un array para guardar las piezas:

```
let piezas = [];
piezas.push(new pieza("a7", "9820", "torre_negra_1", "a7", false));
piezas.push(new pieza("b7", "9822", "caballo_negro_1", "b7", false));
piezas.push(new pieza("c7", "9821", "alfil_negro_1", "c7", false));
piezas.push(new pieza("d7", "9819", "reina_negra_1", "d7", false));
piezas.push(new pieza("e7", "9818", "reina_negra_1", "d7", false));
piezas.push(new pieza("f7", "9821", "reina_negra_1", "f7", false));
piezas.push(new pieza("g7", "9822", "reina_negra_1", "g7", false));
piezas.push(new pieza("h7", "9820", "reina_negra_1", "h7", false));
```

De este modo puedes usar recorrer el array y llamar a la función `colocar()` de cada pieza:

```
piezas.forEach(pieza => pieza.colocar());
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas usar la funcion [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval), para evaluar el string usado:

**index2.js**

```
....
for (let index = 1; index < 9; index++) {
    eval(ejemplo[index]).colocar();

}
```

Comment: Usar eval no es generalmente una buena idea, por seguridad y rendimiento

Comment: Gracias, con la función eval  si que funciona. ¿Qué problemas puede conllevar su uso?

Comment: @user1798310 Puedes leer esta pregunta y las respuestas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192300/en-qu%c3%a9-momento-se-vuelve-necesario-usar-la-funci%c3%b3n-eval-de-javascript

Comment: Se recomienda tener cuidado con la funcion eval() ya que se asume un riesgo el evaluar cadenas de texto que pueden tener codigo que vulnere la seguridad de tu página.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval