# ¿Como operar un string en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este script que tiene un string: '1+1+1+1+1', ahora, quiero operar esa cadena para que me muestra el resultado de la suma de cinco unos

```js
operation = '1+1+1+1+1';
console.log(parseInt(operation)+parseInt(operation)+parseInt(operation)+parseInt(operation)+parseInt(operation));
```

Mi problema es que, estoy agregando varios parseInt, para convertir en entero toda esa cadena, pero solo me convierte el primero, por eso agrego varios y lo sumo con otros parseInt para que me pueda operar. Ahora digamos que si el string no fuera '1+1+1+1+1' sino '1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1' la operacion cambia el numero de caracteres del string y el signo de mas por menos. Entonces ¿Existe alguna manera de operar strings dependiendo del signo y cantidad de caracteres? , gracias.

Comment: Estás confundiendo lo que hace `parseInt`, lo que está pasando es que está tratando de convertir tu string en un número y empieza por el primer dígito... Cuándo encuentra un + la función falla y retorna este primer número, sin procesar el resto de la string, si haces tu ejemplo con `operation = '5+1+1+1+1';` no vas a lograr la funcionalidad que buscas.

Comment: Examina la respuesta que te ofrece @BetaM abajo. Y, piensa como modificarías para identificar los operadores en las iteraciones, estableciendo el operador activo y luego al leer el siguiente número usas el operador detectado en lugar de +=

Comment: si la respuesta que ofrece @BetaM resulta ser optima solo para las operaciones de suma del 1 a 9, he encontrado problemas con las demas operaciones  resta, multiplicacion, division, potencia, etc. Por ejemplo: el string '1-1-1-1' da -4 en vez de -2 al cambiar total -= parseInt(numero), no critico porque aun soy novato en el mundo de la programacion y si lo fuera tampoco lo haria. Igual agradezco la respuesta de BetaM

Answer (score 3):

Yo haría lo siguiente:

- Declaro una variable donde acumularé el resultado de la suma
- Itero los elementos del *string*
- Con ayuda de una expresión regular evalúo si el valor recuperado en cada iteración es numérico, así evito a los símbolos de suma
- En caso de ser numérico lo sumo y acumulo en la variable declarada al inicio
- Por fuera del ciclo imprimo a la variable que acumuló la suma
- Aquí puedes [leer más al respecto del uso de `parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt)

Código

```
let numeros = '1+1+1';
let total = 0;

for(let numero of numeros) {
    if (/[0-9]/.test(numero)) {
        total += parseInt(numero);
    }
}

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Convendría que le comentes por qué no utilizaste el **desaconsejado** método eval( cadena ) ya que cabe esperar que se encuentre con el.

Comment: @quevedo me parece haber visto sobre eval explicado en alguna publicación de la comunidad, si la encuentro la anexo como recursos extra a leer

Comment: @quevedo efectivamente sabía que en algún lado estaba mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192300/en-qu%C3%A9-momento-se-vuelve-necesario-usar-la-funci%C3%B3n-eval-de-javascript

Comment: Excelente enlace. Muy buenos argumentos. Valdría la pena que se incluya en las referencias.

Answer (score 0):

Después de buscar información por varios sitios webs, encontré una solución a esto, usando `RegExp`, `isNaN()` y `test()`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  var button = document.querySelector('button'),
      operation = "1+1+1+1+1+1"

  button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    alert(evaluar(operation))
  });

  const evaluar = expr =>{

  let suma = /(\d+)\+(\d+)/

  if(isNaN(Number(expr))){

    var operar;

    if (suma.test(expr)){

      operar = expr.replace(suma, (operador, a, b)=>{

        return Number(a) + Number(b);

      });

    }

  return evaluar(operar)

  }

  return Number(expr);

  }

})
```

```html
<button>¿Cuánto es 1+1+1+1+1+1?</button>
```

Debo aclarar, que esa expresion regular solo es valida para sumas de un digito que luego precede el signo de mas y luego va un digito, Ejemp: 1+10, no seria valido para: -1+1 | 1.1+2 . Aunque eso se puede resolver facil con la siguiente expresion `/((?:\-\d+)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/` . Si no entiendes expresiones regulares, visita este [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)