# JavaScript: ¿Hay alguna forma de "imitar" la funcion eval() de python en JS?

Tags: javascript

Les explico: Estoy haciendo un asistente de voz web, y quiero añadirle un comando que sume 2 digitos, por ejemplo, le dices "¿Cuanto es 2 + 2?" y te responda "El resultado es 4"

Para hacerlo, tengo esta duda que queria compartir con esta comunidad ¿Hay alguna funcion que tu le des una cuenta en string (por ejemplo: `let cuenta = "2 + 2"`) y luego te devuelva el resultado y en numero entero? En python esta la funcion `eval()` que tu le pasas un string y te da el resultado

Ejemplo: `eval("2 + 2")` Resultado: `4 // es entero`

Si no la hay, ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer una casera... o hay una alternativa?

No tengo ningun codigo que dar porque es lo que se me ocurrio pero no se como llevarlo a cabo

Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192300/en-qu%c3%a9-momento-se-vuelve-necesario-usar-la-funci%c3%b3n-eval-de-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript también cuenta con una función igual. Tanto que se llama `eval`.

Desconozco si se puede usar en backends o en otros lugares pero sí en el frontend.

```js
console.log(eval("2 + 2")) // 4
```

Más información: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Se puede usar en cualquier entorno, pero en general es mejor no usarla nunca

Comment: Gracias! No lo sabia